# How to create trigger in C# local database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created local database in C#, I want to decrease/increase specific values when another column from another table has inserted.

For instance:

Table Book

```
bookName
remain
```

Table MyBook

```
bookName
amount
```

Whenever I insert the book to `Mybook(amount)` I want to reduce remain in `Book` table.

I want to use a SQL trigger in order to implement this, but I don't know how to create trigger in C# local database. Or can I use others method or should I use Sqlite?

**UPDATED** this is how my database was created: Visual studio -> solution explorer -> add new items -> local database -> follow the wizard
Please help

Comment: Are you refering to Visual Studio? you can actually do it with Stored procedrues, why not use it instead of triggers?

Comment: I think you are talking about LocalDb database server which Visual Studio uses by default. Am I right?

Comment: @youji.xii yes i'm using visual studio, i'm not sure if i can create stored procedures in my local database, i don't even know how to create query in my database, can you give me more detail

Comment: @KiranVarsani i think it is LocalDb the procedure i use to created is solution explorer - add new items - local database and followed the wizard

Comment: @soulivong what version of VS are you using?

Comment: @KiranVarsani, youji.xii Visual studio 2010

Comment: @soulivong - I am afraid triggers, stored procedures and other objects are not supported in VS for local DB( .sdf file ).

Comment: @youji.xii  should I create database externally. how about Sqlite or another database

Comment: I think using Stored Procedure to insert the data would be the best approach in your case. I have added an answer showing a stored procedure for the same.

Comment: @soulivong - use MSSQL Express edition instead. :-) its for free. With MSSQL you can create stored procs and other objects. Here is a [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx)

Comment: @youji.xii does it look like SQL server management studio, I found it hard to implements my program using those databases, therefore i prefer local database

Comment: @soulivong - I see. :-) Whichever fits your taste, you can check out SQLite. There are lots of choices I may not know actually. So you may want to google it.